# How do you combine two bookmarklets into one to toggle brightness?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bookmarklet

I'm looking to combine these bookmarklets into one bookmarklet for toggling image brightness by clicking the bookmarklet in the bookmarks bar:

```
javascript:(function(){!function(e) {e.head.appendChild(e.createElement("style"))
  .innerText = ".img,img{-webkit-filter:brightness(50%)}"}(document)})()
```

and:

```
javascript:(function(){!function(e) {e.head.appendChild(e.createElement("style"))
  .innerText = ".img,img{-webkit-filter:brightness(100%)}"}(document)})()
```

I tried doing it myself, but I failed since it has been a long time since I used javascript. Any help would be appreciated with either the coding or by pointing me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by pressing "+" or "-". Check it:

javascript:(function(d,b,s){s=d.head.appendChild(d.createElement("style"));d.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){if (e.key=='+'&&b<100)b+=10;else if(e.key=='-'&&b>0)b-=10;s.innerText = ".img,img{-webkit-filter:brightness("+b+"%)}"})})(document,100)

**Update:**

javascript:(function(d,id,b,s){s=d.getElementById(id);if (!s)d.head.appendChild(s=d.createElement("style")).id=id;b=s.brightness=150-(s.brightness || 100);s.innerText = ".img,img{-webkit-filter:brightness("+b+"%)}"})(document,"bookmarklet-brightness")

Comment: Thank you, it works! This is more than what I wanted, as I have adjusted the requirement, as I forgot to mention I wanted it to make it toggle by clicking the bookmarklet itself, without using any keys. Would it be possible to make it work without using any keys?

Comment: yes. it is little more complex, you have to check for footprints left by previous bookmarklet run. best candidate is the stylesheet that bookmarklet left in the document.

Comment: @rd51 , i release new version. please check

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as I wanted it to! :D I've also modified your code for toggling between 50% and 100% brightness, by using "+" and "-". Could I post it? And if I can, where should I do it, in the comments section, or should I update your current answer by appending the code?

Comment: @rd51: you can post it as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Artyom Shegeda's code I managed to get to toggle the image brightness between 50% and 100% by pressing the "+" and "-" keys, by using the following code:

```
javascript:(function(d,b,s){
  s=d.head.appendChild(d.createElement("style"));
  d.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.key=='+'&&b<100)
       b+=50;
    else if (e.key=='-'&&b>50)
       b-=50;
    s.innerText = ".img,img{-webkit-filter:brightness("+b+"%)}"
  })
})(document,100)
```